# Why do I get different results when I use requests and aiohttp respectively？

Tags: python, python-requests, aiohttp

Here is my code

```
import requests
import aiohttp, asyncio

url = 'https://www.alliedelec.com/automation-control/control-station/'
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'
}
text1 = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
print(text1)
async def fun():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, headers=headers) as resp:
            text2 = await resp.text()
            print(text2)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.ensure_future(fun()))
```

`requests` can get the right results, the
correct HTML source code. But aiohttp get a
`aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientOSError`.
Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/my/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.ensure_future(fun()))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 468, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "E:/my/test.py", line 12, in fun
    async with session.get(url, headers=headers) as resp:
  File "D:\manyvenv\tornado_api_server\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1005, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "D:\manyvenv\tornado_api_server\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 497, in _request
    await resp.start(conn)
  File "D:\manyvenv\tornado_api_server\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 844, in start
    message, payload = await self._protocol.read()  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "D:\manyvenv\tornado_api_server\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 588, in read
    await self._waiter
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientOSError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

What's the difference between requests's request and aiohttp's request?

python==3.6.5, aiohttp==3.5.4, requests==2.23.0

THANKS!

Comment: Could you edit your answer and add some more information of what kind of error you get from aiohttp?

Comment: Please add the __full__ error message traceback into your question - for both the different types of error. And what is the “right” results?

Comment: @barny,@Emil Stenström. I added more detailed error information. And I found that aiohttp will not report an error under centos7, but it will report an error under win10.I'm more confused

Comment: I tried your code on my slightly more recent setup (Python `3.8.2`, aiohttp `3.6.2`, ArchLinux) and it worked OK. The exception your're getting indicates the server is closing the connection (maybe it detected your *host/headers* combination for aiohttp as a bot). Do you get an OK response on `centos7`?

Comment: yes, i got an ok response on `centos7` with both `requests` and `aiohttp`, but on win10,`requests` is ok, but `aiohttp` got an error